# redirect url doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I set up a website in a folder, with a redirect: my_site.com/folder/index.php redirects to my_site.com.
I updated the site, and moved it to the root. So I don't need that redirect anymore. It's now my_site.com.

However ... I got a few complaints from visitors who bookmarked it, and can't get there anymore. So I tried to set up a redirect, but that doesn't work. It throws a loop:

```
    You cannot redirect "my_site\.org\/folder\/index\.php" to "http://my_site.org" as this will cause a redirection loop because "/home/folder/public_html" is the document root of one of your domains.
```

(I removed the actual address.) How do I solve this problem? Some visitors are looking with their browsers for an url that no longer exists.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Add your htaccess config.